# Reproducir Audio con la funcion delay Javascript en móviles

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para Audiometría en la que genero un delay aleatorio (entre 1 y 5 segundos) pasados los cuales se reproduce un sonido. Esto funciona correctamente en PC, sin embargo no en móviles.

http://www.audiometria.esy.es

HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>TEST AUDIOMETRICO <span id="onAndroid"></span>- RESULTADO:<span id="resultado"></span></h1>
    <audio id="song" controls preload="auto">
        <source src="1MHz.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <br><br><br>
    <button id="start2" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Comenzar
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
    </button>
    <br><br><br>
    <h1 class="button">
        <span id="btn-listen" class="glyphicon glyphicon-record playbutton"></span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

BOOTSTRAP MODAL

```
<!-- /.modal -->
<div id="instructions-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title modal-titulo">Examen Audiometrico</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="modal-title modal-titulo">Instrucciones</h4><br>
                <ul>
                    <li class="modal-pagraph">Para una correcta evaluación se recomienda el uso de auriculares.</li>
                    <li class="modal-pagraph">Procure realizar el examen en un ambiente libre de ruido.</li>
                    <li class="modal-pagraph">Si detecta que el volumen del sonido es demasiado alto, reduzcalo.</li>
                    <li class="modal-pagraph">Sus oidos serán evaluados individualmente, el primero será el izquierdo.</li>
                    <li class="modal-pagraph">Durante el examen, solo debe presionar el botón <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span> cuando escuche un sonido.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Comenzar
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#instructions-modal').modal('show')
});
$('#start').click(function () {
    $("#start2").remove();
    var status = 'off';
    var delay = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1)) * 1000;
    var clicks = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
        //$("#song").play();
        document.getElementById("song").play();
        status = 'wait';
    }, delay);

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (status == 'wait') {
            status = 'failure'
        }

        $('#resultado').text(status);
        console.log(status);
    }, delay + 3000);


    $('#btn-listen').click(function () {

        if (status == 'wait' && clicks == 0) {
            status = 'success'
        } else {
            status = 'failure'
        }
        clicks = clicks + 1;
    })
});
```

Comment: Comprueba que se haya cargado del todo el mp3 antes de lanzar el timeout, podría ser que en un móvil tarde mas en cargar el mp3 que el tiempo que espera.

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto, para dispositivos móviles, el `autoplay` está deshabilitado (al igual que la carga automática) para evitar que el usuario incurra en uso de datos no esperado. Y para que el sonido comience se requiere una acción del usuario.

Puedes leer más sobre el tema en la web de [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) (traducción mía):

> En Safari en iOS (para todos los dispositivos, incluido iPad), en donde el usuario puede estar usando red de datos y pagando por unidad de datos, la precarga y autoplay están deshabilitados. Ningún dato se carga hasta que el usuario lo indique. Eso significa que los métodos `play()` y `load()` estarán inactivos hasta que el usuario inicie la reproducción, `play()` y `load()` serán llamados por acción del usuario. En otras palabras, un botón de Play pulsado por el usuario funcionará, pero `onLoad="play()"` no lo hará.

Aunque tienes el `play()` dentro de un click, no está funcionando, lo cual podría ocurrir por alguno de estos motivos:

1. El `play` está siendo ignorado porque, aunque iniciado en una función lanzada por una acción del usuario, se encuentra en un `setTimeout` y el navegador entonces no lo considera acción iniciada por el usuario.
2. La canción tarda en cargarse más de 3 segundos, lanzándose el mensaje de error antes de que suene (porque no se empieza a cargar hasta que se pulse en el botón).

En esta [otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983731/html5-audio-object-doesnt-play-on-ipad-when-called-from-a-settimeout) de StackOverflow en inglés con un problema similar, [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10983845/3695983) sugiere una posible solución que adaptada a tu pregunta sería hacer lo siguiente:

1. Ejecuta el `play()` dentro del código que se llama al hacer `click`.
2. Justo después del `play()` pon el audio en pausa con `pause()`.
3. Llama a la función dentro del `setTimeout` de la misma manera que tienes ahora.

Como el `play()` original se realiza dentro de una acción iniciada por el usuario en lugar de un `setTimeout` el navegador cargará el audio y a partir de ahí deberías poder trabajar con él de manera normal sin problemas.

Prueba a hacer eso y dime si te funciona.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo he probado y funciona a la perfección.

Comment: @AlejandroGutierrez si esta respuesta funciona y te sirvió, acéptala como respuesta correcta pulsando en el ✓ que hay en la esquina superior izquierda.